# @Html.DropDownListFor How to add option?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ZipFile, new SelectList(ViewBag.ZipFiles))
```

The above code creates me a select list just fine. But I want to make the selection optional. Unfortunately there is no empty option and I'd like to add one in. How would I do this?

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By using the [proper DropDownListFor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561.aspx):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.ZipFile, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.ZipFiles),
    "-- please select a zip file --"
)
```

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 10):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new List<SelectListItem>
   {
     new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "1"},
     new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "2"},
     new SelectListItem { Text = "Sreelanka", Value = "3"},
     new SelectListItem {Text  = "Africa",Value="4"},
     new SelectListItem { Text = "China", Value = "5" },
     new SelectListItem { Text = "Austraila", Value = "6" },
     new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "7" }
  }, "Select Country", 
  new {@Style = "Width:500px;height:40px;",
  @class = "form-control input-lg"})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, when you set ViewBag.ZipFiles, add a SelectListItem to that collection.