# Setting Conditional Attributes in Razor for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I tried [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399531/asp-net-mvc-razor-conditional-attribute-in-html), but it seems like this may be handled differently in the latest version of ASP.NET Core. I got no `selected` attribute at all from this:

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Status">
    <option></option>
    @foreach (var option in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StatusOptions))) {
        <option value="@option" @{if (option == Model.Status) { <text>selected="true"</text> } }>@option</option>
    }
</select>
```

As an alternative, I tried this and got `selected="selected"`, but Visual Studio gives me a warning that `@selected is not a valid value of attribute of 'selected'`.

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Status">
    <option></option>
    @foreach (var option in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StatusOptions))) {
        bool selected = option == Model.Status;
        <option value="@option" selected="@selected">@option</option>
    }
</select>
```

I can use that, but I have to ignore the warning and it doesn't render exactly what I want. Is there a way to get:

```
<option value="firstOption" selected>firstOption</option>
```

Comment: You do not set the `selected` property. The Tag Helper does that based on the value of the property you binding to. - `<select asp-for="Status" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<StatusOptions>()"></select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I would not enumerate the StatusOptions here.  I would probably put this as a property on my Model.

```
public List<SelectListItem> StatusOptions => Enum.GetNames(typeof(StatusOptions)).Select(o => new SelectListItem {
   Text = o,
   Value = o,
   Selected = o == this.Status
}).ToList();
```

Then in the razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, Model.StatusOptions, new { @class="form-control", asp_for = "status" })
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to add an empty first option to that helper or does it need to be injected into the `StatusOptions` list?

Comment: Yes... you can add a string you want for the empty option:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9294117/788509

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make sure `Model.Status` will be the same type as `option` in `foreach`

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Status">
        <option></option>
        @foreach (var option in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StatusOptions))) {
            <option value="@option" @{option == Model.Status ? "selected" : ""} }>@option</option>
        }
    </select>
```